# Sending email to 2 recipients using SKPSMTPMessage

Tags: iphone, email, skpsmtpmessage

I used  SKPSMTPMessage in my iPhone application. Problem is with multiple recipients. I just need to send email to two recipient.

I'm using the following code:

```
-(void)sendEmail {

// create soft wait overlay so the user knows whats going on in the background.
[self createWaitOverlay];

//the guts of the message.
SKPSMTPMessage *testMsg = [[SKPSMTPMessage alloc] init];
testMsg.fromEmail = @"support@dsfaes.co.uk";
//  testMsg.toEmail = phone;
testMsg.toEmail=@"manjinderr@gmail.com;

testMsg.relayHost = @"smtp.nman.co.uk";
testMsg.requiresAuth = YES;
testMsg.login = @"support@man.co.uk";
testMsg.pass = @"nfsdxsdfswdrt";
testMsg.subject = @"The Confirmation";
testMsg.wantsSecure = YES; // smtp.gmail.com doesn't work without TLS!

// Only do this for self-signed certs!
// testMsg.validateSSLChain = NO;
testMsg.delegate = self;
}
```

Anyone knows how can i send email to 2 recipient

Comment: Check this issue: http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/issues/detail?id=18&q=multiple

Comment: This code makes no sense mate. i have already searched it

Comment: Manjinder S, i have given the heck solution for this, i hope it help you any way. see my answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the `heck` solution for this

**First Create the recipientsArray which contains your recipients**

```
NSArray* recipientsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"abc@abc.com",@"xyz@xyz.com",nil];
```

**Call you sendEmail method**

```
for(NSString* toEmailAddress in recipientsArray){
   [self sendEmail:toEmailAddress];
}
```

**Then define your sendEmail method:**

```
-(void)sendEmail:(NSString*)_toEmailAddress {
    // create soft wait overlay so the user knows whats going on in the background.
    [self createWaitOverlay];

    //the guts of the message.
    SKPSMTPMessage *testMsg = [[SKPSMTPMessage alloc] init];
    testMsg.fromEmail = @"support@dsfaes.co.uk";

    testMsg.toEmail = _toEmailAddress;
    testMsg.relayHost = @"smtp.nman.co.uk";
    testMsg.requiresAuth = YES;
    testMsg.login = @"support@man.co.uk";
    testMsg.pass = @"nfsdxsdfswdrt";
    testMsg.subject = @"The Confirmation";
    testMsg.wantsSecure = YES; // smtp.gmail.com doesn't work without TLS!

    // Only do this for self-signed certs!
  // testMsg.validateSSLChain = NO;
  testMsg.delegate = self;
}
```

Comment: I will try and let you know:-)

Comment: Ok @Manjinder S, and is your earlier problem solved? location one(ggogleurl ?

Comment: Where should i put recipientsArray=[@"abc@abc,com,@"dfa.com""]; and for loop?  in sendEmail: method?

Comment: No Mr. Parveen. not yet. let me try this first then i tell you about that,

Comment: @Manjinder S wherever you were calling your sendEmail method earlier. when you were calling sendEmail method before ? for example **lets assume** you were calling in viewDidLoad or on any button action there you just call like recipientsArray = [@"abc@abc.com",@"xyz@xyz.com"];
for(NSString* toEmailAddress in recipientsArray){
   [self sendEmail:toEmailAddress];
}

Comment: Yes i was calling it in button action. but it shows error at [@"abc@abc.com",@"xyz@xyz.com"]; says use of undeclared recpientArray

Comment: @Manjinder S you seriously need to learn objC seriously, if it say recpientArray is undeclared it means you need to declare it. ok wait i edit my answer to **solve your error. **

Comment: yah i declared it using NSArray *recepientArray

Comment: It shows warning then i used  NSArray *recipientsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"manjinderdfdr@gmail.com",@"maddfar@hotmail.co.uk",nil];

Comment: Now it says use of undeclared identifier '_toEmailAddress' infront of  testMsg.toEmail = _toEmailAddress;

Comment: Mr. Control V i have sent u mail on gmail. please have a look if u get time. n reply. thanks